# Static block initialization of two classes leads to a confusion

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, static-block, classloading

in the following code

```
public class MyClass {
    
static int a;
int b ;
    static {
        a = 10;
        System.out.println("MyClass a= "+a);
    }
    {
        b = 20;
        System.out.println("MyClass b= "+b);
    }
    

}
 

public class VariableInitialization {
    
static int a;
int b ;
    static {
        a = 10;
        System.out.println("VariableInitialization a= "+a);
    }
    {
        b = 20;
        System.out.println("VariableInitialization b= "+b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VariableInitialization v ;
        MyClass m;
    }

}
```

The Output is always

VariableInitialization a= 10
VariableInitialization b= 20

why its always getting initialized for VariableInitialization but why not for MyClass?

Comment: How are you using these two classes? What is your **confusion**? Please **edit** your question to clarify. Because you are dangerously close to incoherence.

Comment: Local variables not initialized. Why do you think it should print something? It should print only if you create an object of that class. The two classes has no relationship. Only runtime dependency on the first class gives nothing to a second class.

Comment: If one assumes your invoking the `VariableInitialization` class via the java launcher (e..g. `java VariableInitialization`) then perhaps the question is: why does the instance initializer block of `VariableInitialization` get executed?  Add specifically how you are testing this.

Comment: from eclipse of course 

@Computable 

so you are saying just because i am running the code using java command it is loadig the VariableInitialization class and executing the blocks ?

Comment: These two are seperate files .

1. VariableInitialization.java
2. MyClass.java